# Visual studio compiler errors at enum

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have the following code which compiles without errors under Linux and Mac OS X. I now want to compile the code with Windows, but I get a lot of errors in the following code segment:

```
...
enum Type   
    {
        UPDATE = 0, DELETE = 1
    };
...
```

The error messages are these:

```
1>Request.hpp(48) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before '('
1>Request.hpp(48) : error C2059: syntax error : '<L_TYPE_raw>'
1>Request.hpp(49) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>Request.hpp(49) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

What did I wrong, I am really confused, as this compiles without errors under Linux.
What can cause this errors?

Comment: Post the code above and below the enum definition. Also, point out the line numbers in the code so we can understand which line corresponds to which line in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I found my error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is quite easy, but one need to find out that DELETE is a Macro defined in the windows header.

I now added #undef DELETE and it works fine.

Comment: `DELETE` is not a Visual Studio keyword.  The Windows headers define a macro called DELETE for defining access control masks.

Comment: Thanks, I am quiet new to Visual Studio, I change it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Type` is an existing class. You need to change the name or specify that it's a literal.

You could try `enum @Type` to specify a literal, though you may need to prefix it with `@` elsewhere.